# Android checkbox + listview issue

Tags: android, listview, button, checkbox

Each item of my listview contains a checkbox.

I want the `CheckBox` to be checked/unchecked whenever i click on a row of my `ListView`. Now, the `CheckBox` and the `ListView` item are two separated things, which means i can click on the `ListView` item ("behind" the checkbox) or on the `CheckBox`.

The problem is that if I click on the `CheckBox`, it doesn't trigger the **itemClickListener** (which is logical since they are separated).

So what i want is for the items and checkboxes to work "as one".

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

**Activity:**

```
listView.setAdapter(new FoodTypeAdapter(this, foodTypeList));
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.foodType);
            if (cb.isChecked()) {
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
            }
        }
    });
```

**Adapter:**

```
private boolean[] checkBoxState;

public FoodTypeAdapter(Context context, List<FoodType> foodTypeList) {
    this.foodTypeList = foodTypeList;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    checkBoxState = new boolean[foodTypeList.size()];
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected CheckBox foodType;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View newView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        newView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.food_type_row, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.foodType = (CheckBox) newView.findViewById(R.id.foodType);
        newView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        newView = convertView;
    }

    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) newView.getTag();

    holder.foodType.setText(foodTypeList.get(position).getName());
    holder.foodType.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);
    holder.foodType.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                checkBoxState[position] = true;
            } else {
                checkBoxState[position] = false;
            }
        }
    });

    return newView;
}
```

**ListView row:**

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/foodType"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="Checkbox"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

I know alot of topics about this already exist but i haven't found one with the same issue...

Help me please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should make your `CheckBox`s to not being click able by setting `android:clickable="false"` in your xml. then when users clicks on items, and `OnItemClickListener` fires, you should toggle your `CheckBox`'s state manually.

Comment: I don't use any `EditText` in this activity ... I don't get your answer

Comment: sorry, it was a mistake. i mean `CheckBox`. see my edited answer.

Comment: Well as you can see in the code I posted, `android:clickable` is already set to `false`

Comment: then, maybe you should create a custom view , with a check box state drawable and not clickable and use that instead of default check box.
but I think if you set click able to false, your view should not intercept touch event.

Comment: @clementino36 I think when you set clickListener to your check box, it will set check box clickable to true implicitly. remove that listener and I think everything will be fine.

Comment: I removed the checkbox clickListener, so now wherever i click, the item of the listView is triggered, but the checkbox state doesnt change :/

Comment: of course. as I mentioned in my answer, you should set check box state manually. maybe you can store a list of booleans for that or add a boolean field to your data set for storing each item check box state and check/clear that according to that state.

Comment: Thank you for you time, now i have it working as i wanted to! 
But can you help me for one more thing ? Now i want to get the position of the checked items by clicking on a button so i can send the position in an extra to the next activity ...

Comment: your welcome. maybe you should accept my answer now :)
I think I didn't get your problem. is there a button on each item? or there is a button outside of your list?

Comment: Done! There's a button outside of the list which should find the checked item's position integer so i can send that integer to the next activity

Comment: you can obtain the position form your data set or your list of booleans that you use to store check boxes state. I don't know the structure of your data set, so I can't help much.

Comment: Ok i will try to solve it and get back here if I don't manage, thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

I think you should apply only *onclicklistener* on your *newView* which will be activated when the view is clicked and then u can toggle the checkbox on the basis of its position.